# XPathEvaluator is undefined’ script error in Microsoft Dynamics CRM using IEDriverServer and Internet Explorer through Selenium and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, dynamics-crm, internet-explorer-11

I am testing a CRM application using Selenium Java. 
There is a button on the CRM application which when clicked opens a new window.
When I run the test for this functionality, the new window opens and there is a **Script Log Error** which in the body says,

> ReferenceError: 'XPathEvaluator' is undefined at (**some http resource**)

But when I try the same functionality manually, it works fine and does not cause any error. 
What I am trying to understand is, what causes the **XpathEvaluator is undefined** error.

Any help to understand this error would be appreciated. Or some hint towards where I can start my investigation for the same.

I have already checked the xpaths involved in clicking the button and opening the window. They are correct locators.

The versions I am using:

- Selenium: 3.14
- IE: 11

Comment: There is little information here. I would suggest you to log the XPathEvaluator result before the offending code, and also to verify the common situation in which the page content is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ReferenceError: 'XPathEvaluator' is undefined
```

...implies that there was a *ReferenceError* while *XML processing* in *Javascript*.

@nzakas (Wrox Author), in the *XML processing in Javascript* section of his book *Professional Javascript for Web Developers* mentioned, historically there are some browsers that won't work with the `XPathEvaluator`. He further stated that, users should use the corresponding methods pertaining to the specific *Document* to make up for the short coming in those browsers.

Specifically, [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) is the only browser that now doesn't support **`XPathEvaluator`**. You can use `selectNode()` and `selectSingleNode()` on the *DOM Document object* instead (for IE only).

---

### This usecase

As per the article, [Resolving the Error "XPathEvaluator’ is undefined"](https://www.qgate.co.uk/knowledge/resolving-the-error-xpathevaluator-is-undefined/) this `XPathEvaluator is undefined` script error is often observed in *Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011* after upgrading to [internet-explorer-11](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-11). Further investigation revealed, any HTML resource that includes `ClientGlobalContext.js` (which is used to get the context of the parent form) will throw the error the error `SCRIPT5009: ‘XPathEvaluator’ is undefined`.

---

### Solution

A quick solution will be to add the following line to the `<head>` of your custom HTML documents that reference that particular *JS* file:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

This this line of the *script* is to force the browser to run the web resource in [internet-explorer-10](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-10) mode.

> **Caution**: The downside is that this functionality will be depreciated in [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge), which is Microsoft’s newly released *Internet Explorer* replacement.

Comment: I am sorry if this is a beginners question but you are saying that the error occurs because CRM isn't compatible with IE-11. It doesn't explain why I dont get the same error when I try doing it manually? The script error occurs only when I run tests?

Comment: @PratikshaB Did you read the complete answer? Did you browse through the different links and documentations from the answer?